# How to add a label to each stratum to display additional information in a rank-change chart using alluvial in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to graphing with ggplot2, I am currently working on data visualization, specifically I am developing alluvial graph that aims to support decision making. I have been working for days and I have two problems that I have not been able to solve

I am graphing from an Excel file that contains the following:

`PositionRank    AlarmsName  AlarmCount  Week        RankMove
1                 Alarm F       272     LastWeek    DOWN
2                 Alarm B       231     LastWeek    DOWN
3                 Alarm A       221     LastWeek    DOWN
4                 Alarm C       125     LastWeek    UP
5                 Alarm E       112     LastWeek    DOWN
6                 Alarm D       108     LastWeek    DOWN
7                 Alarm H       102     LastWeek    DOWN
8                 Alarm G       98      LastWeek    DOWN
9                 Alarm I       88      LastWeek    UP
10                Alarm J       80      LastWeek    UP
1                 Alarm C       221     CurrentWeek UP
2                 Alarm F       165     CurrentWeek DOWN
3                 Alarm B       133     CurrentWeek DOWN
4                 Alarm A       124     CurrentWeek DOWN
5                 Alarm J       109     CurrentWeek UP
6                 Alarm E       105     CurrentWeek DOWN
7                 Alarm H       101     CurrentWeek DOWN
8                 Alarm I       95      CurrentWeek UP
9                 Alarm D       90      CurrentWeek DOWN
10                Alarm G       80      CurrentWeek DOWN`

Based on other questions asked in this community and some documentation, I have obtained the following flood graph where the left and right areas indicate  the 10 alarms that were most activated  (denoted by 10 colored blocks).

[image]

Here two colors are used: red represents the alarm that appears or increases in the ranking; green indicates the alarm that disappears or decreases in the ranking.

- First of all I need to show last week on the left side and current
  week on the right side, I have tried doing this by trying to reverse the order of the data frame but have not had any results.
- Secondly I would like to show the name of the alarm, show the number
  of times it was activated during the week(AlarmCount), here I have tried to add
  labels with geom_text () but I have not obtained results worth
  showing.

My idea is to get a graph similar to this:

[image]

This is the code I have been using and the excel file.

`library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)#install.packages("dplyr")
library(readxl) #install.packages("readxl")
library(ggplot2)#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggalluvial)



    PositionRank=rep(seq(1,10,1), times = 2)
    AlarmsName =c("Alarm F","Alarm B","Alarm A","Alarm C","Alarm E","Alarm D","Alarm H","Alarm G","Alarm 
    I","Alarm J"
              ,"Alarm C","Alarm F","Alarm B","Alarm A","Alarm J","Alarm E","Alarm H","Alarm I","Alarm 
    D","Alarm G")
    AlarmCount= c(272,231,221,125,112,108,102,98,88,80,
              221,165,133,124,109,105,101,95,90,80)
    Week = 
 c("CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek","CurrentWeek",
         "LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek","LastWeek")
    RankMove = c("DOWN","DOWN","DOWN","UP","DOWN","DOWN","DOWN","DOWN","UP","UP"
             ,"UP","DOWN","DOWN","DOWN","UP","DOWN","DOWN","UP","DOWN","DOWN")
    data = data.frame(PositionRank,AlarmsName,AlarmCount,Week,RankMove)

    print(data)
    ggplot(data,
           aes(x = Week, stratum = AlarmsName, alluvium = AlarmsName,
               fill = RankMove, label = AlarmsName, y = AlarmCount ))+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("green3", "red"))+
      geom_stratum(alpha = 1, decreasing = FALSE,)+
      geom_alluvium(decreasing = FALSE,knot.pos = 0)+
      geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 5, decreasing = FALSE)+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = 
    element_blank(),text = element_text(size = 10))`

I also leave the excel if necessary, which is exactly the same as the dataframe created in the code.

[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-7TGIGxP0H5LJUVIPrxHuK3auAW07lP/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you very much in advance and good morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code below, you can get this graph. I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for. I am not sure how to draw the boxes for the labels so that they are the same height as the segment.

[image: One Solution]

```
data = data.frame(PositionRank,AlarmsName,AlarmCount,Week,RankMove)
```

After creating the data frame, I am factoring the Week variable so that it appears in the order you want. Then I am adding two variables for the labels in the graph. The running totals allow me to put the values where they need to be in the graph.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(Week = factor(Week, levels = c("LastWeek", "CurrentWeek"))) %>% 
  arrange(Week, AlarmCount) %>% 
  group_by(Week) %>% 
  mutate(running_total_Last = ifelse(Week == "LastWeek", 
                                     cumsum(AlarmCount) - .5 * AlarmCount, NA_integer_),
         running_total_Current = ifelse(Week == "CurrentWeek", 
                                        cumsum(AlarmCount) - .5 * AlarmCount, NA_integer_)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(Week, PositionRank)
```

In the plot, I am using the running totals to create the labels with geom_label.
You may need to play around with the `nudge_x` arguments to get it to look right for the dimensions you are using to visualize the graph.

```
  ggplot(data2,
         aes(x = Week, stratum = AlarmsName, alluvium = AlarmsName,
             fill = RankMove, label = AlarmsName, y = AlarmCount))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green3"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green3"))+ #Making the color the same as the fill
  geom_stratum(alpha = 1, decreasing = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_alluvium(decreasing = FALSE,knot.pos = 0, show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 5, decreasing = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = 
          element_blank(),text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  geom_label(aes(y = running_total_Last, label = AlarmCount, color = RankMove), 
             fill = "white", nudge_x = -.22, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(y = running_total_Current, label = AlarmCount, color = RankMove),
             fill = "white", nudge_x = .22, show.legend = FALSE)+
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```