# Sankey chart in Python

Tags: python

I would very much like to make an illustration like the one in the link:

[How to add a label to each stratum to display additional information in a rank-change chart using alluvial in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559588/how-to-add-a-label-to-each-stratum-to-display-additional-information-in-a-rank-c)

I have trouble doing it in Python as it creates multiple linked [figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQRJD.png) which I do not want. My script is:

`import plotly.graph_objects as go`

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A1, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 9, 6, 7, 8],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2,1, 0, 2, 3]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the structure of the data. eg You’ve defined 10 unique source nodes. Generally you’d have a smaller number of nodes than links. ie each source node is linked to only one target, leading to these linear chains and isolated networks. The labels are just decorative. The node identity is defined in the source and target vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Sankey dialog on the official site, I will edit it to show the data structure between the ABs. Simply put, the source is A, the target is B, and the rest is an iteration of that. The additional labels as shown in the link in your question are not available in plotly's sankey dialog as far as I know. You'll have to get creative with the labels. I will add a text based explanation of what I am doing.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"], 
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                target = [5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 5], 
                value =  [8, 4, 3, 2, 6, 3 ,4 ,5, 2, 4] 
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()

# Data structure
# labels  ->  A1 A2  A3  A4  A5  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
# positon -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9]

# souce[0], value[0], target[0]
# [position](lables):[0]("A1") -> [8] -> [5]("B1")
# souce[1], value[1], target[1]
# [position](lables):[1]("A2") -> [4] -> [6]("B2")
# souce[2], value[2], target[2]
# [position](lables):[2]("A3") -> [3] -> [8]("B3")
...
```

[image]

Comment: I am relatively new to python and have only used it for 3 days, as I only need to make this illustration. I tried to copy the code you shared into jupyter notebook and it kept saying "SyntaxError: invalid syntax to the sign "->"

Comment: Sorry, that code was created in text to illustrate the data structure. I just made it a comment. The lines to copy are up to `fig.show()`.